# can't load native library for csipsimple when .so files are copied?

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native, pjsip

I'm trying to copy already existing old `libpjsipjni.so` file to my jniLibs android studio code with  compileSdkVersion 21 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2" when copied and compile it says `libraryjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dlopenfailed:cannot locate symbol"...`

How to make it compatible especially in android M (6.0) please help i am stuck at this.

Comment: The so file should be under armeabi or another directory. Which symbol cannot be located? Do you specify app_platform for NDK build?

Comment: yes the .so file are under armeabi/armeabi v-7a directory im not building the native code just using the .so file libraryjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:dlopenfailed:cannot locate symbol "BN_nist_mod_521" referenced by "/data/app/com.myapp/lib/arm/libpjsinjni.so

Comment: This symbol belongs to openssl libraries. If your library uses dynamic link to preinstalled openssl, it may not work on M or higher: the built-in implementation of ssl has changed in Android. Also, the new build system forbids linking system SO files (except the "official" ones that are bundled with NDK). But you can build openssl yourself and bundle it with your app. Note that Play Store verifies the bundled implementation of openssl (too many exploits for outdated versions of openssl).

Answer (score 0):

You have probably been hit by https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#IssuewithusingOpenSSLonAndroidM. The solution is to build openssl yourself and bundle it with your app. You can try your luck with a prebuilt library (see https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt/tree/master/openssl-1.0.2). Note that Play Store verifies the bundled implementation of openssl (too many exploits for outdated versions of openssl).

Comment: i have no experience in building native files can you please specify a little how to build it ?

Comment: I believe that you should try a prebuilt library then